# How can i close the vue popover when i scroll the screen

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, touch-event, bootstrap-vue

I haven't decided any popover for Vue.
Device is Touch devices
For touch devices I need click event for opening of popover.
Scenario:
I used Vue bootstrap popover or tooltip
it is stuck to the screen when I am scrolling.
I need to remove when scrolling

Answer (score 4):

You can use this snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    do_sth() {
      this.$root.$emit('bv::hide::popover')
    }
  },
  created () {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.do_sth);
  },
});
```

```css
body .wrapper {
    padding: 100px 20px;
    min-height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
<div class="wrapper">
<b-button
  href="#"
  tabindex="0"
  v-b-popover.click="'Popover content'"
  title="Popover title"
>
  Link button with popover directive
</b-button>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: If the scrolling is in div

Comment: Yes you can use query selector like: `document.getElementById('your-div-id').addEventListener('scroll', this.do_sth)`

Comment: what if there are lot of popovers and i want to toggle that popover. And i am using v-b-popover term

Comment: As i am using v-b-popover.hover because i wanted it to work in desktop and touch devices too

Comment: @Ameetdeadpool Please open a question and share what you try and errors you get.